# How to interact with the compiler within VSCode?

Tags: vscode

Sometimes, I made a typo, so the compilation fails,
which leads to an incomplete aux file.
This file causes problems the next time I want to compile.
Usually it says

> File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.

So now comes the problem, how can I tell the compiler to skip (`enter`),
to skip forever (`s`+`enter`), or to stop (`x`+`enter`)?
There doesn't seem to be an obvious place I can interact with the compiler.

Comment: If you use vscode extension `latex-workshop`, then setting [`"latex-workshop.latex.autoClean.run": "onFailed"`](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#latex-workshoplatexautoCleanrun) may help. Also I believe `latex-workshop` is powerful enough to define your own cleaning-up recipe which only delete aux.